# Extract only additions from diff in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, diff, difflib

I am trying to solve a problem:
I receive auto-generated email from government with no tags in HTML. It's one table nested upon another. An abomination of a template. I get it every few days and I want to extract some fields from it. My idea was this

1. Use HTML in the email as template. Remove all fields that change with every mail like Name of my client, their Unique ID and issue explained in the mail.
2. Use this html template with missing fields and diff it with new emails. That will give me all the new info in one shot without having to parse this email.

Problem is, I can't find any way of loading only these additions. I am trying to use `difflib` in python and it returns byte streams of additions and subtractions in each line that I am not able to process properly. I want to find a way to only return the additions and nothing else. I am open to using other libraries or methods. I do not want to write a huge regex with tons of html.

Comment: if you have HTML then maybe you should use modules for HTML/XML like `lxml` or `beautifulsoup`

Answer (score 0):

When I got the stdout from using Popen calling diff it also returned bytes.
You can convert the bytes to chars, then continue with your processing.
You could do something similar to what I do below to convert your bytes to a string
The below calls diff on two files and prints only the lines beginning with the '>' symbol (new in the rhs file):

```
#! /usr/env python

import os
import sys, subprocess

file1 = 'test1'
file2 = 'test2'
if len(sys.argv)==3:
    file1=sys.argv[1]
    file2=sys.argv[2]

if not os.access(file1,os.R_OK):
    print(f'Unable to read: \'{file1}\'')
    sys.exit(1)
if not os.access(file2,os.R_OK):
    print(f'Unable to read: \'{file2}\'')
    sys.exit(1)

argv = ['diff',file1,file2]
runproc = subprocess.Popen(args=argv, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = runproc.communicate()
outstr=''
for c in out:
    outstr+=chr(c)
for line in outstr.split('\n'):
    if len(line)==0:
        continue
    if line[0]=='>':
        print(line)
```